# Bokeh plot with initially hidden/muted legend groups

Tags: python, bokeh

Essentially I want [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html), but where when the plot loads, some legend entries are already muted or hidden and the user clicks to show them.
[image]

I have tried to hunt around Bokeh's docs but can't find the setting I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code does what you want (tested on Bokeh v1.0.4). You just need to set the `visible` property on your glyph renderer.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 250, x_axis_type = "datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'

stocks = ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"]
lines = {}
for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], stocks, Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    lines[name] = p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width = 2, color = color, alpha = 0.8, legend = name)

lines["AAPL"].visible = False

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"

output_file("interactive_legend.html", title = "interactive_legend.py example")
show(p)
```

Result:

[image]